# How to execute laravel WHERE along with EloquentFilter

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause, laravel-5.5

I am using this [EloquentFilter](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter) to filter Database on the frontend and the controller below works

```
public function indexArtisan(Request $request)
{
    $workers = Worker::filter($request->all())->get();
    $states = DB::table('states')->pluck("name", "id");
    return view ('artisans', compact('states'))->with(['workers' => $workers]);
}
```

However, when i try to use the WHERE query to add conditions to the data been called with the controller, the WHERE condition is met and data returned but my filter no longer works. domain.com?name=xyz

```
public function indexArtisan(Request $request)
{

    $work = DB::table('workers')->where('career', '=', 'artisan')->get();
    $workers = Worker::filter($request->all())->get();
    $states = DB::table('states')->pluck("name", "id");

    return view ('artisans', compact('states','work'))->with(['workers' => $workers]);
}
```

Also tried

```
$work = DB::table('workers')->where('career', '=', 'artisan')->get();
    $worker = $work->filter($request->all());
    $states = DB::table('states')->pluck("name", "id");

    return view ('artisans', compact('states'))->with(['worker' => $worker]);
```

I get [image: Error screen]

How do i execute the WHERE condition without breaking the filter
I've read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses i still cant figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Isn't `$workers = $work->filter($request->all());` working for you?

Comment: i get this error "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\Collection::filter() must be callable or null, array given, called in .../app\Http\Controllers\WorkerController.php on line 28" @Bart

Comment: Please read more on Eloquent filter here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter and create your own function for that...

Comment: pardon me for intruding, i just noticed.. where is this `where` that combined with your `->filter()`? as far as i see the eloquent filter, it adds a bunch of `where`s. see that `$work` and `$workers`? i mean, you create two different query, and we have no idea what you did to it on the sink (read: view). i believe you do  things to `$work` only without messing the `$workers`.

Comment: @Umar745 please include changes to your code with eventual errors...

Comment: Hi @Umar745, pardon me for being not helpful. i want to ask, i only wish to clarify on your explanation: "*However, when i try to use the WHERE query to add conditions to the data been called with the controller, the WHERE condition is met and data returned but my filter no longer works.*", what i saw, you called the `->where()` and `::filter()` on two different places.. sorry if you end up offended with my question.

Comment: Edited the question to include the code and eventual error. @Bart

Comment: Yes i called the where and the filter on two different place because I want to get data that meets the where condition and then filter those data using the filter package "eloquentfilter".  It clearly isn't working which is why i need help @BagusTesa

Comment: *want to get data that meets the where condition and then filter those data using the filter package "eloquentfilter"*, i see, that much clearer. does `$workers = Worker::filter($request->all())->where('career', '=', 'artisan')->get()` not working? as far as i am aware, that eloquent filter adds more `where`s.. chaining them with another where should not be a problem.

Comment: It works! @BagusTesa  Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$work->filter($request->all());` the filter() method is the method of collection class, because $work is a collection now.

So, you need to use filter() method of model class

```
DB::table('workers')->where('career', 'artisan')->filter($request->all())->get();
```

should work.

Comment: I get Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder\::Filter does not exist.

Comment: Try Worker::where('career', 'artisan')->filter($request->all())->get();